# Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition when setup Magento 2.0 (0.1.0-alpha107)

Tags: magento2, database

Today I set up a version of Magento 2.0 (build 0.1.0-alpha107). But the process has stuck at 23% with error:

```
Exception 'PDOException' with the message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause'.
```

Here are some pieces of the error log:

Module 'Magento_Sales': 
Include

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/Magento/Sales/sql/sales_setup/install-2.0.0.php 
[ERROR] exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/setup/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

Comment: What is the problem? Magento2 has one table which is setup incorrect, because "there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to MySQL 5.6

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/782

Magento 2 Requirements: https://github.com/magento/magento2#magento-2-system-requirements